# Add a filter based on other column values in kdb

Tags: database, kdb, q-lang

I have a column containing symbols like EURUSD, USDINR etc. I need to create a new column based on the condition that if any of the first three or last three alphabets of the currency pairs belongs to this list
ref: ("INR", "BLR"....)
then I have to create a new column "result" and update it as "yes" if condition is satisfied otherwise "No".

Can anyone please help me with this. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given

```
q)show t:([]pair:`EURUSD`USDINR`BLRUSD`INRBLR`BLREUR)
pair
------
EURUSD
USDINR
BLRUSD
INRBLR
BLREUR
```

and

```
q)ref:`USD`EUR
```

the straightforward query to add the described "result" column would be

```
q)update result:((`$3_'string pair)in\:ref)or(`$3#'string pair)in\:ref from t
pair   result
-------------
EURUSD 1
USDINR 1
BLRUSD 1
INRBLR 0
BLREUR 1
```

but the following alternative will probably be faster:

```
q)update result:0<count each ref inter/:`$0 3_/:string pair from t
pair   result
-------------
EURUSD 1
USDINR 1
BLRUSD 1
INRBLR 0
BLREUR 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Give the same example table `t` and references `ref` from Alexanders example you can also build up a list of matching start and end sequences:

```
q)show m:{raze(s,\:"*";"*",/:s:string(),x)}ref
"USD*"
"EUR*"
"*USD"
"*EUR"
```

Then find the pairs that match those:

```
q)update max each pair like/:\:m from t
pair   m
--------
EURUSD 1
USDINR 1
BLRUSD 1
INRBLR 0
BLREUR 1
```

When also considering the time to build the list `m` and run the query this example is less efficient than above. If you only have to build the list `m` then this example may be more efficient, but it will depend on the size of the list `ref`.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative. Check for ref in each pair and OR over each pair of values in the resultant list

```
q)ref:`USD`EUR
q)update result:(|/')ref in/: `$0 3_/: string pair from t
pair   result
-------------
EURUSD 1
USDINR 1
BLRUSD 1
INRBLR 0
BLREUR 1
```